# What method to add in NearablesDemoActivity.java

Tags: java, android, estimote

I'm working on a project for Shoe sticker using estimote sticker and facing some problems. I'm using android studio for my project

I have error at **dbRow = stickerdb.getResult(currentNearable.identifier("065473d63cd9d687"));**

***It says Method call expected***

***The error log:
Error:(96, 52) error: cannot find symbol method identifier(String)***

```
public class NearablesDemoActivity extends BaseActivity {

private static final String TAG = NearablesDemoActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Nearable currentNearable;
private BeaconManager beaconManager;
private String scanId;

TextView Desc;  //description
Spinner spinnerDropDown;  //for size available
String[] size = {
};                   //for size available
Spinner spinnerDropDown2;   //for colours available
String[] colour = {
};                      //for colours available
TextView COO;      //For country of origin
TextView SM; //For Shoe Model
TextView Price; //For price
Button btnRating;  //for button
private Database_sticker stickerdb;
Sresult dbRow;

@Override
protected int getLayoutResId() {
    return R.layout.nearable_demo;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.nearable_demo);


    currentNearable = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(ListNearablesActivity.EXTRAS_NEARABLE);
    displayCurrentNearableInfo();

    beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item ,size);  //for size available
    spinnerDropDown.setAdapter(adapter);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1= new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item ,colour); //for colours available
    spinnerDropDown2.setAdapter(adapter1);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_navigation_arrow_back);
    toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    btnRating=(Button)findViewById(R.id.rd);

    btnRating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent pageforRatingBar = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RatingBar_main.class);
            startActivity(pageforRatingBar);
        }
    });

    stickerdb = new Database_sticker(this);
   // dbRow = stickerdb.getResult(1);//currentNearable.identifier()
    dbRow = stickerdb.getResult(currentNearable.identifier("065473d63cd9d687"));
    dbRow.getSa();
    dbRow.getDesc();
    dbRow.getCoo();
    dbRow.getId();
    dbRow.getPrice();
    dbRow.getSm();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    beaconManager.setNearableListener(new BeaconManager.NearableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNearablesDiscovered(List<Nearable> nearables) {
            updateCurrentNearable(nearables);
            displayCurrentNearableInfo();

        }
    });


    beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceReady() {
            scanId = beaconManager.startNearableDiscovery();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    beaconManager.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

private void displayCurrentNearableInfo() {
            Desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);   //for description
            // Get reference of SpinnerView from layout/nearable_demo.xml
            spinnerDropDown = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);  //For size available
            spinnerDropDown2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);//for colours available
            COO = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);//for country of origin
            SM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview3); //for shoe model
            Price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview4); //for price
}

private void updateCurrentNearable(List<Nearable> nearables) {
    for (Nearable nearable : nearables) {
        if (nearable.equals(currentNearable)) {
            currentNearable = nearable;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `identifier()` should be a String type method of `Nearable` class. Is it?

Comment: Yes but I have no idea where to put it

Comment: What do you mean? From your snippet I can say that you have created one `Nearable` class right, in that class create a method `identifier()`

Comment: How do I create a method in that class? Sorry I'm new to android and still in the process of learning, I'm learning as I'm doing this project

Comment: It's a bad idea to start learning Android without learning Java and OO first. You need to learn to walk before you learn how to run.

Comment: I know that but I have little time left, this is project given to me, I have to rush it

Comment: If I were you, I would dump the project and start learning core Java first even if I get failed in semester or expelled from job.

Comment: I thought this is a forum to help? So I came here hoping some ppl would help me

Comment: @Apurva, I'm really hurt to hear that.

Comment: My intention wasn't to hurt you but if you want good career in programming then learn. :) Google how to create method in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling an `identifier` **method** on an object of the `Nearable` class. There is no such method in this class:

http://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/com/estimote/sdk/Nearable.html

There is, however, an `identifier` **property**, and that's the one you need to use:

http://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/com/estimote/sdk/Nearable.html#identifier

In other words, this line:

```
dbRow = stickerdb.getResult(currentNearable.identifier("065473d63cd9d687"));
```

… needs to become:

```
dbRow = stickerdb.getResult(currentNearable.identifier);
```